# ¿Cómo generar un GeoJson desde Java Spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, geojson

estoy trabajando con Spring Boot para poder generar un GeoJson y posteriormente poder reflejar las coordenadas a un mapa de Google Maps.
Actualmente genero un Json teniendo mi clase con el Modelo, así como también mi Query (tengo las coordenadas alojadas en la B.D de Mysql)
No soy capaz de hacer un GeoJson, que es lo que deseo realizar, es decir quiero generar de acuerdo a la información de la B.D un geojson y así proyectarlo en un Mappa de Google.

Tengo mi clase Modelo de la siguiente manera (para recibir mis datos desde la B.D):

```
package com.geologistic.model;

public class PaqueteJson {
    private String nombreEscaneo;
    private String latitud;
    private String longitud;
    public String getNombreEscaneo() {
        return nombreEscaneo;
    }
    public void setNombreEscaneo(String nombreEscaneo) {
        this.nombreEscaneo = nombreEscaneo;
    }
    public String getLatitud() {
        return latitud;
    }
    public void setLatitud(String latitud) {
        this.latitud = latitud;
    }
    public String getLongitud() {
        return longitud;
    }
    public void setLongitud(String longitud) {
        this.longitud = longitud;
    }
    public PaqueteJson() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public PaqueteJson(String nombreEscaneo, String latitud, String longitud) {
        super();
        this.nombreEscaneo = nombreEscaneo;
        this.latitud = latitud;
        this.longitud = longitud;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PaqueteJson [nombreEscaneo=" + nombreEscaneo + ", latitud=" + latitud + ", longitud=" + longitud + "]";
    }


}
```

Este es el Query para obtener los datos:

```
public List<PaqueteJson> findJson()
{
    List<PaqueteJson> paquetes= jdbcTemplate.query("select * from agencia ", new RowMapper<PaqueteJson>() {

        public PaqueteJson mapRow (ResultSet rs, int argl) throws SQLException{
            PaqueteJson paquete = new PaqueteJson (rs.getString("nombreEscaneo"),rs.getString("latitud"),
                                            rs.getString("longitud"));
            return paquete;
        }
        });
    return paquetes;

}
```

Mediante el Controllador, genero mi Json actual (pero realmente deseo obtener un Geojson):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<PaqueteJson>> getTimelineProjectCaptions() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<PaqueteJson>>(paqueteService.findJson(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Este es el Json que se genera actualmente:

```
[{"nombreEscaneo":"SALIDAS ALBACETE","latitud":"39.018922","longitud":"-1.875926"},{"nombreEscaneo":"SALIDAS PLATAFORMA BAILEN","latitud":"38.085772","longitud":"-3.773147"}, ....
```

Pero en deseo obtener un geojson de tipo "LineString" con las coordenadas obtenidas, y así reflejarlo en un Mapa.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola. ¿Pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: Hola @K. Cisneros, puedes usar la librería [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/). Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Hola @Angel tengo la noción de cómo hacerlo pero aún no logro hacerlo funcionar como deseo.

Comment: @elgerar gracias, miré tu ejemplo y me ayudó a darme una idea de cómo hacerlo, aunque se me es un poco confuso el controlar los objetos (hacer que palabras vayan saliendo en qué orden). Saludos!

Comment: Hola @K.Cisneros, si encontraste una solución debes añadir una respuesta en lugar de añadirla a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN**

```
JSONObject featureCollection = new JSONObject();
        featureCollection.put("type", "FeatureCollection");
        JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();
        properties.put("name", "ESPG:4326");
        JSONObject crs = new JSONObject();
        crs.put("type", "name");
        crs.put("properties", properties);
        featureCollection.put("crs", crs);

        JSONArray features = new JSONArray();



        // ciclo for
        for (PaqueteJson obj : paqueteService.findJson()) {
            JSONObject feature = new JSONObject();
            feature.put("type", "Feature");
            //JSONArray JSONArrayCoord = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject geometry = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject desc = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject newFeature = new JSONObject();


            //JSONArrayCoord.put(0, Double.parseDouble(obj.getLongitud()));
            //JSONArrayCoord.put(1, Double.parseDouble(obj.getLatitud()));
            JSONArray JSONArrayCoord = new JSONArray("[" + obj.getLongitud() + "," + obj.getLatitud() + "]");

            geometry.put("type", "Point");
            geometry.put("coordinates", JSONArrayCoord);
            feature.put("geometry", geometry);
            // proper.put("properties", desc);
            feature.put("properties", desc);
            desc.put("name", obj.getNombreEscaneo());


            features.put(feature);
            featureCollection.put("features", features);

            // System.out.println(featureCollection.toString());
            // }

        }
        System.out.println(featureCollection.toString());
```

fuentes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068226/loop-through-a-list-and-create-a-geojson-dynamically-in-java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986806/create-geojson-using-simple-json-java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311526/how-to-convert-java-object-in-to-geojson-required-by-d3-graph

y muchos otros sitios más...

Comment: Hola, me podrían echar una mano ??? Me pasa exactamente lo mismo pero con postregssql. La estructura del json es válida pero no me lo lee mapbox. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316015/c%C3%B3mo-generar-un-geojson-con-springboot-y-postgressql

Answer (score 0):

Además de usar la libreria [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/) puedes crearlo usando el objeto `JSONObject`

Te dejo un ejemplo de como construirlo.

Dado un ejemplo de GeoJson como este:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
            "name": "ESPG:4326"
            }
    },
    "features":[

    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[55,55]
                },
        "properties":{
                "desc":"something"}
                }
    ]
}
```

Se puede crear un con el siguiente código:

```
JSONObject featureCollection = new JSONObject();
featureCollection.put("type", "FeatureCollection");
JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();
properties.put("name", "ESPG:4326");
JSONObject crs = new JSONObject();
crs.put("type", "name");
crs.put("properties", properties);
featureCollection.put("crs", crs);

JSONArray features = new JSONArray();
JSONObject feature = new JSONObject();
feature.put("type", "Feature");
JSONObject geometry = new JSONObject();

JSONAray JSONArrayCoord = new JSONArray();

JSONArrayCoord.add(0, 55);
JSONArrayCoord.add(1, 55);
geometry.put("type", "Point");
geometry.put("coordinates", JSONArrayCoord);
feature.put("geometry", geometry);

features.add(feature);
featureCollection.put("features", features);
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Disculpa, después de darle vulta me eh decidido a escribirte.
No logro hacer que tu ejemplo en codigo me de tu ejemplo en json (aún modificando) entonces me gustaría saber como logras que te salga en ese orden (el ejemplo de geojson que me diste) el geojson generado es {"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[55,55],"type":"Point"},"type":"Feature"}],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"ESPG:4326"}},"type":"FeatureCollection"}
 y si lo ingreso a un validor de mapa no lo lee, pero si ingreso tu geojson d ejemplo dado sí. Cómo lograste que apareciera en esa secuencia? Gracias

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo tomado, encontré la solución, en todos los posts estaban incorrectos los Json, porque faltaban atributos o en algunos otros tenían mal los elementos, es por eso que no encontraba la solución.
Como nota, es necesario el elemento de propiedades dentro de cada coordenada sino, no carga en mapa (lo pusiste en ejemplo, pero faltó en código)
Sin duda tu respuesta fue una de muchas para orientarme.
Edito mi pregunta dejando la solución por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.
Gracias!