# Cómo generar un geojson con springboot y postgressql

Tags: spring-boot

Intento generar un ***geojson*** a partir de los datos que extraigo de la base de datos. La base de datos está ***postgresql***.

Conseguí realizar la consulta para obtener los datos, pero me gustaría saber cómo hacerlo de manera eficiente, ya que la información que se extrae puede ser de un fichero de muchas megas o incluso gigas.

Así que mi problema es que me gustaría saber cómo generar un ***geojson*** para luego almacenarlo de forma física y que no consuma mucha ram.

No tengo mucha experiencia con `springboot`.

¿Cómo hago un microservicio para generar el fichero ***geojson*** a partir de los datos de la base de datos?

Gracias

Este es el código que he hecho para hacer la llamada:

```
public String getGeoJsonFromTable(String nameTable) {
        String SQL = "SELECT table_id, CAST(properties AS text) as properties, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as geometry FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id ASC;";               
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL);

        JSONObject geojson = new JSONObject();
        geojson.put("type", "FeatureCollection");

        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("type", "Feature");
            jsonObject.put("id", result.get(i).get("table_id") );
            jsonObject.put("geometry",  serializeProperty( result.get(i).get("geometry").toString() ) );
            jsonObject.put("properties", serializeProperty( result.get(i).get("properties").toString() ) );
            json.put(jsonObject);
        }
        geojson.put("feautures", json);
        return geojson.toString();
 }


private JSONObject serializeProperty(String property) {
    JsonObject gson = new JsonParser().parse(property).getAsJsonObject();
    return new JSONObject(gson.toString());
}
```

Me devuelve un geojson con la estructura válida pero no con el orden de los campos. Y por lo tanto no me lo lee mapbox.

Me lo tendría que devolver así: `{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"1","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[...]}}]}`

Pero me lo devuelve así: `{"feautures":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[...],"type":"Polygon"},"id":1,"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"}}],"type":"FeatureCollection"}`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO!!

Gracias por vuestra ayuda :D

Estoy muy tonto, el error estaba en que `geojson.put("feautures", json);` tiene que ir dentro del bucle para ser un geojson valido. Es decir, ya era un json válido pero no un geojson válido AGHGHH.

Además, creo que he optimizado el código.

```
public String getGeoJsonFromTable(String nameTable) {
    String SQL = "SELECT table_id as id, CAST(properties AS text) as properties, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as geometry FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id ASC;";             
    List<Feature> listFeatures = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL ,new RowMapper<Feature>() {
        public Feature mapRow(ResultSet result, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Feature feature = new Feature();
            feature.setId(result.getInt("id"));
            feature.setGeometry(result.getString("geometry"));
            feature.setProperties(result.getString("properties"));
            return feature;
        }
    });

    JSONObject featureCollection = new JSONObject();
    featureCollection.put("type", "FeatureCollection");

    JSONArray features = new JSONArray();

    for (Feature featureObject : listFeatures) {
        JSONObject feature = new JSONObject();
        feature.put("type", "Feature");
        feature.put("id", featureObject.getId());
        feature.put("geometry", serializeProperty(featureObject.getGeometry()));
        feature.put("properties", serializeProperty(featureObject.getProperties()));
        features.put(feature);
        featureCollection.put("features", features);
    }
    return featureCollection.toString(); 
}
```